# Java Date issue

Tags: java, date

I am using GregorianCalander and when i tried to get todays date using the following code i am getting a date which is backdated to one month. The code i have used is as follows.

```
        Calendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        today = getTime(gcal);
        //date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("Today: " + today);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

The output is :

> Today: Thu Apr 28 00:00:00 NZST 2011

EDIT

```
private Date getTime(Calendar gcal) {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String day = form_helper.round(gcal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        String month = form_helper.round(gcal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH));
        String year = form_helper.round(gcal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR));
        String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(date));
        return sdf.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(timesheet_utility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the code for getTime ?

Comment: Month indexing starting at 0 is the issue it seems

Comment: WTF? I have no idea... I know they're a bit backward in the Eastern State, but a whole MONTH behind... WTF? Are you sure your PC's date is right? And BTW... post your actual code... `today = getTime(gcal);` won't compile (atleast it won't this month).

Comment: Now I just HAVE to ask... Why have you gone to such mindbendingly complex lengths to get todays date? I must be missing something, surely?

Comment: @ corlettk: I am using this date with mysql to get records so i have to convert it to string is a specified format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think internal numbering of months starts with 0, not 1. So, you probably need to somewhere add +1.
Edit: after you showed some more code: The needed change is

```
String month = form_helper.round(gcal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
```

Comment: Good Answer then, but now outdated. The `Calendar` & `GregorianCalendar` classes were replaced by `ZonedDateTime` in Java 8+. See JSR 310.

Answer (score 4):

What does the `getTime()` method do? Remember that in Java, the constants for the month begin at 0 and not at 1, so [`Calendar.JANUARY == 0`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

**EDIT**

Since you posted the code for `getTime()` I think this is the problem:

`gcal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)` returns the month value that Java internally stores, that is, a 0-indexed month value so a value for "May" would actually be the integer "4".

When the value "4" is put back into the date parser, "April" results, since the parser interprets dates as a human would. So you simply have to add 1 to this value to ensure the parsing happens properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a `Date` object that represents 12:00AM (or 00:00) for today, why not just do:

```
private Date getTime() {
    Calendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
    gcal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    gcal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    gcal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    gcal.set(Calender.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return gcal.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Looking back to 2011 I was asking myself the same question.If modifying the existing `GregorianCalendar` is a no-no, make a copy and apply this trick. However, and more important, in 2024 no one should use neither `GragorianCalendar` nor `Date` anymore. Use `LocalDate` from java.time for a date.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
package forums;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Deepak
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      (new Deepak()).run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date today = calendar.getTime();
    System.out.println("Today: " + today);
  }

}
```

and the output is the expected:

```
 Today: Sat May 28 22:00:52 EST 2011
```

Comment: I believe that the OP expected the time in the output to be 00:00:00 (not 22:00:52).

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

The terribly flawed `Calendar` & `GregorianCalendar` classes are now legacy, years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `LocalDate`

For date-only values, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

To capture the current date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by time zone. It can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while simultaneously “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;  // Or `ZoneId.systemDefault`. 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If the time zone is omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

To generate text in a specific format, use `DateTimeFormatter` class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
String output = today.format( f ) ;  // Generates text in a custom format.
```